# Conservation of angular momentum with a circular disk and a person at the rim

Tags: momentum

So, I was reading my textbook in the section regarding net torque, and they gave an example of a seesaw with one person at each end, and they said that there is a net external torque due to the force of gravity on each person. I completely understand that; however, when I was reading another section of my textbook, they were talking about the conservation of angular momentum, which only happens when the net torque is zero. So they gave an example of a circular disk that rotates freely in a horizontal plane about a frictionless, verticle axle. On top of that, there is a person who walks slowly from the rim of the disk towards the center. The textbook modeled this problem as conservation of angular momentum problem, but why? Isn't the weight of the person causing an external torque just how the weight of the two people in the seesaw caused a net external torque?

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question... Please let me know if I am wrong. If we choose the system as the circular disk with the person, then there is NO external torque acting on the system. However, there are internal torques acting on the particles. For instance, there is mgr acting on the circular disk and then there is friction acting on the person.

Comment: Also recall that the direction of linear acceleration for a non-accelerating rotating object is towards the center (centripetal acceleration), which means the torque is zero. Therefore the friction that is acting on the human/disk has no net torque.